# Wt with Qt, .pro settings

Tags: qt, wt

I am trying to get Wt working with Qt. I have installed 1.47 boost library, compiled Wt (3.2.1) under Windows using cmake 2.8.8. Tired simple hello world but doesn't compile, getting undefined reference errors for example:
    undefined reference to `Wt::WApplication::WApplication(Wt::WEnvironment const&, Wt::WtLibVersion)'

```
Here is my .pro file:    
QT       -= core

QT       -= gui

INCLUDEPATH += ../../../lib/Wt/include \
          ../../../lib/boost_1_47 \
          ../../../lib/Wt/src

LIBS += -L../../../lib/Wt/lib \
    -L../../../lib/boost_1_47/lib

win32:LIBS += -lwthttpd -lwtd -lboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47

TARGET = HttpServerWt
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

This is the program I am trying to compile:
http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/hello

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your WT libraries will be added to `/usr/loca/lib` by default. so specify link libraries accordingly[after checking whether its present there, else check in `/usr/lib` and include accordingly].

Set `LIBS` Variable as follows

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lwtd -lwthttpd -lboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47
```

I don't see any Problem in setting the `INCLUDEPATH` variable in your post.

And also make sure that you are adding the module corresponding to `Wt::WApplication::WApplication(Wt::WEnvironment const&, Wt::WtLibVersion)` in `LIBS` Variable.

For more [look here](http://redmine.emweb.be/wiki/wt/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q-How-do-I-build-my-newly-written-Hello-World-application).

Comment: ok add the path respective to windows instead of -L/usr/local/lib in LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lwtd -lwthttpd -lboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47..That would do

Comment: Isn't that already done using -L and -l? Thank you for your replays.

Comment: Tried it on unix .. working without any problems. Shame I need it on Windows.

Comment: I haven't done it in windows. But is win32:LIBS += -lwthttpd -lwtd -lboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47 right? Or win32:LIBS += -L../../../lib/Wt/lib -lwthttpd -lwtd -lboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47???

Comment: Erm .. it's the same if you add this line before:     LIBS += -L../../../lib/Wt/lib \
    -L../../../lib/boost_1_47/lib
 and then add this: 
win32:LIBS += -lwthttpd -lwtd -lboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47. I am thinking there might be a problem with compiling Wt in VS. Will google how to compile in Qt and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more libraries, because in Ubuntu you need to add more than two libraries to compile a wt code with qt creator.

Here is my *.pro file

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = prueba3
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lwt -lwthttp -I/usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lwthttp -lwt -lboost_regex -lboost_signals
LIBS += -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_date_time
#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DNDEBUG

CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

and it compiles/Build great, finally you must add this line to run settings(ctrl+5)

```
--docroot . --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 9090
```

Comment: This is again a unix version solution, seems my question wasn't formed correctly :/

Comment: I wanted to tell you that maybe you need to add those others libraries "-lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_date_time"

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! The question pointed out to specific missing symbols - which I think are in one of the WT libraries, nothing to do with boot.